# printf() with multi-threading

Tags: c, multithreading

I don't understanding the behavior of `printf()` here. If I lock the whole function, then the print out would be fine. But, if I modified the code so that it only lock the code has data dependency, one thread never gets ended?
Here's the code:

`queue_lock` is the problem.

```
    void *professor_write(int *param){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pro_id_update);
        param[0]++;
        int id = param[0];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pro_id_update);

        printf("STARTING Professor %d\n", id);
        //Each professor assigning <num_assignings> times
        for(int i = 0; i < param[1]; i++){
                int num_assignments; 
                if(param[5] == param[4])
                        num_assignments = param[5];
                else{
                //Random number of assignments in range min_num_assignment ~ max_num_assignment
                        num_assignments = rand() % (param[5] - param[4]) + param[4];
                }
                for(int j = 0; j < num_assignments; j++){
                        int wait_time;
                        if(param[3] == param[4])
                                wait_time = param[3];
                        else{
                        //Random wait time in range min_prof_wait ~ max_prof_wait
                                wait_time = rand() % (param[3] - param[2]) + param[2];
                        }
                        sleep(wait_time);
                        int hours;
                        if(param[7] == param[6])
                                hours = param[6];
                        else{
                        //Random hours range in min_assignment_hours ~ max_assignment_hours
                                hours = rand() % (param[7] - param[6]) + param[6];
                        }
                        struct assignment tmp;
                        tmp.hours = hours;
                        tmp.numberOfStudents = param[8];
                        tmp.prof_id = id;
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_lock);
                        //queue is full wait for students to read
                        while(param[9] == count)
                                printf("full\n");
//                              pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &queue_lock);
                        fprintf(stdout, "ASSIGN Professor %d adding Assignment %d: %d Hours\n", id, in, hours);
                        queue[in] = tmp;
                        in = (in + 1) % param[9];
                        count++;

                        //signal student the queue is not empty
//                      pthread_cond_signal(&fill);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_lock);
                }
        }
        printf("EXITING Professor %d\n", id);
        pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Sample output:

```
num_assignings: 4
min_prof_wait: 1
max_prof_wait: 5
min_num_assignments: 1
max_num_assignments: 1
min_assignment_hours: 1
max_assignment_hours: 5
num_professors: 2
num_students: 2
students_per_assignment: 2
queue_size: 256
STARTING Professor 1
STARTING Professor 2
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 0: 4 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 1: 4 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 2: 2 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 3: 2 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 4: 4 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 5: 4 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 6: 1 Hours
EXITING Professor 2
```

Output if to lock the whole thing:

```
num_assignings: 4
min_prof_wait: 1
max_prof_wait: 5
min_num_assignments: 1
max_num_assignments: 1
min_assignment_hours: 1
max_assignment_hours: 5
num_professors: 2
num_students: 2
students_per_assignment: 2
queue_size: 256
STARTING Professor 1
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 0: 2 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 1: 1 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 2: 3 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 3: 4 Hours
EXITING Professor 1
STARTING Professor 2
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 4: 4 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 5: 2 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 6: 4 Hours
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 7: 1 Hours
EXITING Professor 2
```

Comment: Looking at the log file, it looks like Professor 1 is stuck processing assignment 7.  In the second log file, there are 8 assignments total.  To me it doesn't look like the last processor isn't 'Ending', its getting stuck somewhere else in the function.

Comment: Do I need to lock `printf()` as well? I thought `printf()` is an atomic-like call.

Comment: In some cases, the program runs as predicted. But other times, the eighth element never updated to the queue.

Comment: You have `min_num_assignments` == `max_num_assignments` == 1 and still have more than one assignment per professor?

Comment: Those two variables define how many assignments assign per `num_assignings`. Since `num_assignings` = 4, each professor must produce 4 assignments

Comment: printf is not thread safe, is my thought.  But in case of doubt, it is safer to think it is not and protect it, thant wait to see it failing in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have trimmed down a sample app, which occasionally behaves the same as your posted problem.

To recreate it, I 'forgot' to join on thread 2.
Can you make sure you are joining all your threads, and potentially post the block that is calling the threads?

Based on your comment, I think this is the most likely.  My application exhibits the same behavior, when prof2 finishes before prof1.

> In some cases, the program runs as predicted. But other times, the
>   eighth element never updated to the queue.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_mutex_t queue_lock;
void *professor_write(void *params){

        int prof = ((int*)params)[0];
        int runs = ((int*)params)[1];
        int i;
        printf("STARTING Professor %d\n", prof);
        //Each professor assigning <num_assignings> times
        for(i = 0; i < runs; i++){

                                                sleep(rand() % (5));
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_lock);
                        fprintf(stdout, "ASSIGN Professor %d adding Assignment %d:\n", prof, i);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_lock);

        }
       printf("EXITING Professor %d\n", prof);
        pthread_exit(0);
}


int main()
{

int prof1[2]={1,4};
int prof2[2]={2,4};
pthread_t prof2_thread;
pthread_t prof1_thread;

pthread_create(&prof1_thread, NULL, professor_write, prof1);
pthread_create(&prof2_thread, NULL, professor_write, prof2);

pthread_join(prof1_thread, NULL);
//pthread_join(prof2_thread, NULL); // commented out to force error

return 0;

}
```

And I get this output, either success when prof2 finishes first:

```
STARTING Professor 1
STARTING Professor 2
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 0:
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 0:
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 1:
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 1:
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 2:
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 3:
EXITING Professor 2
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 2:
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 3:
EXITING Professor 1
```

Or when prof1 finishes first ( I changed the rand values to make the other thread first, or you can swap the joins. ):

```
STARTING Professor 1
STARTING Professor 2
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 0:
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 0:
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 1:
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 1:
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 2:
ASSIGN Professor 2 adding Assignment 2:
ASSIGN Professor 1 adding Assignment 3:
EXITING Professor 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that takes care of the problem.

Comment: @firefly - Great, I also added the output, because I wasn't sure.  I haven't ever use pthreads recently ( I use a proprietary thread library for most of my C code ), and wasn't too confident.   But I'm glad it works!